# Replacing wild character in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to replace java wild character ? from string  b.match(/?/g) with \|, using string replaceAll method. I have tried following regex

```
1. /[\^?]/  
2. match[(][/][?][/]g[)]
```

Both regex work fine with tool but while running java code replaceAll method is not replacing string. Java might be considering ? as regex instead of string. Is there any way to solve the issue.

Comment: What is your exact string? Not understanding the question.

Comment: Is your question about how to use `replaceAll()` to replace all `?` characters in a String ? If so just escape the character by writing `\?` instead

Comment: Yes b.match(/?/g) is string. I want to replace ? with \|

Comment: `replaceAll("/\?/", "\|")` should work

Answer (score 1):

> Both regex work fine with tool but while running java code replaceAll
>   method is not replacing string.

`replaceAll` method won't replace your actual `String` it will return new `String` which has replaced data.

```
String s="yourString";
s.replaceAll("a","b");//Won't Change your Actual String
String newReplaced=s.replaceAll("a","b")//For Example
```

Secondly You Need to use Escape Character `\` as `?` and `|` are special characters and reserved characters for `regExp`.

> I am trying to replace java wild character ? from string b.match(/?/g)
>   with \|,

Example:

```
System.out.println("Replace? Marks??".replaceAll("\\?","\\\\|"));
```

Will replace all `?` with `\|`